# Where does that new /swap.img file come from?

Tags: 22.04, swap, lvm

I installed an Ubuntu VM 22.04 LTS running on top of VMware ESXi v7 on the 4th of July 2022 with a dedicated LV for the swap :

```bash
$ swapon --show
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/dm-3 partition  30G   0B   -2
$ lsblk -o +path /dev/dm-3
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS PATH
vg_OS-lv_swap 253:3    0  30G  0 lvm  [SWAP]      /dev/mapper/vg_OS-lv_swap
```

Suddenly appeared a new `/swap.img` file (I don't know when) :

```bash
$ swapon --show
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/swap.img file        8G   0B   -2
/dev/dm-3 partition  30G   0B   -3
```

The server is hosting a postgresSQL DataBase :

```bash
$ dpkg -l | grep "postgresql-.. "
ii  postgresql-12                         12.11-1.pgdg22.04+1                     amd64        The World's Most Advanced Open Source Relational Database
```

What triggered the creation of this new /swap.img file ? :

- the installation of a specific package or
- the `open-vm-tools` package (not installed on my VM but vSphere says in the Summary tab of the Gest OS : `VMware Tools Not running, version:11365 (Guest Managed)` ) or
- the action of another administrator or
- something else

EDIT0 : I'll get the output of the `systemctl list-unit-files swap*` command at work tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure it wasn't there the entire time? Is it in your fstab?

The default installation of Ubuntu 22.04 uses a swap file (/swap.img).  You can get rid of it with:

```bash
swapoff /swap.img
rm /swap.img
```

Then comment out or delete the following line in `/etc/fstab`:

```bash
/swap.img      none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll check this out at work tomorrow.